# Is there a cleaner way to lay this script out?

Tags: javascript

Simply put, I have been getting into javascript (for now, just the simple DOM manipulation stuff... css and that..).

I found a ton of ways to alter CSS on click, or if browser width is a certain size etc... this is the cleanest way I have found so far, and I was ok with it until I started adding in more elements... Now, it works fast enough, there are no errors on the console... And this may just be because I'm new to the language but, is there a cleaner way of doing what I've done here? Meaning something with less writing...

Or is javascript somewhat limited in what it can do with CSS? (hence jQuery)...

I'd prefer to avoid jQuery for now. I'm starting with the roots because I hate using libraries that I don't truly understand. Thanks!*

Please see the snippet below:

```js
// The onclick HTML function

function openNav() {
  // Get the elements
  var a = document.getElementById("menucontrol"),
      b = document.getElementById("overlaycontrol"),
      c = document.getElementById("id01"),
      d = document.getElementById("id02"),
      e = document.getElementById("id03");

  // Add /or remove "__open" to/from classes
  if (a.className === "nav") {
    a.className += "__open",
    b.className += "__open",
    c.className += "__open",
    d.className += "__open",
    e.className += "__open";
  } else {
    a.className = "nav",
    b.className = "overlay",
    c.className = "burger__top",
    d.className = "burger__middle",
    e.className = "burger__bottom";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't add the class to something like the body tag temporarily in order to distribute styles down from that parent element instead? `body.menuOpen { #menucontrol { display: hidden; } }`

Comment: consider using iterators. (e.g. for loop)

Comment: CSS is *cascading*.  A CSS rule `body.x p { color: red}` will make every `p` element red if the **`body`** tag has the class `x`.  You can likely replace all of this with a few CSS rules.

Comment: [Might be better off here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: honestly? i just wanted to have the script alter the css. Not to actually have the css in the script... does that make sense? So what i did was i made the styles for each element and then made the styles for each element when the menu is open (by adding __open to each). If there is a WAY better way then by all means lol like i said, total noob here. I was told to avoid doing css directly in javascript (and also assumed that would be way more writing than what i have now)... thoughts?

Comment: If you take advantage of cascading CSS, you can change a single class in your JS instead of 20.  Think about the example I gave in my previous comment.  That would apply to *every* `p` tag, and it would take *one* line of code to add or remove that class.  That is far, far more manageable than how you're doing it now.  In fact, this is how we theme our entire site.  A single class on the `body` tag is all it takes to change literally everything.

Comment: you know what? NOW i get ya. lol i miread the first time. But yea, that makes PERFECT sense. Thanks to you too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h2oooooooo is right, but as a rule of thumb, whenever you see repetition like that, you can extract it into functions, loops and/or other language constructs. For example, if you really wanted to keep doing what you're doing, you could refactor into something like this:

```
var navOpen = false;

function updateNavClass(id, className) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.className = navOpen ? className + '__open' : className;
}

function openNav() {
    navOpen = !navOpen;

    updateNavClass('menucontrol', 'nav');
    updateNavClass('overlaycontrol', 'overlay');
    updateNavClass('id01', 'burger__top');
    updateNavClass('id02', 'burger__middle');
    updateNavClass('id03', 'burger__bottom');
}
```

And so most of the repetition is gone.

Comment: THIS is literally EXACTLY what i wanted to know. OK so there is one error which i can handle, thats fine. Im literally dissecting this now (how it works) but yes, what i have been trying to learn is how to deal with repetition when each element your working with is slightly different. THANK YOU for this lesson.